# ReactJS send key(index) on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to send element's index on click in function. Because I should change data for every element and get it from array.

How can I get key in `MainBlock` from `List`? Is it possible? Or I do something wrong?

I'm very new in React and do many mistakes.

```
var MainBlock = React.createClass({
Click: function() {
    // I need to get element KEY
    // var data = array[key]
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <List Click={this.props.Click.bind(null, this)}>
    );
}
});

var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var ItemNodes = this.props.data.map(function(step, index) {
            return (
                <Item className="class" Click={this.props.Click.bind(null, this)} key={index} />
            );
        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <ul>
                {ItemNodes}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});

var StepWindow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li onClick={this.props.Click}>
                yo!
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Click={this.props.Click.bind(this, index)}

Click: function(idx, e){

}
```

check out the boundClick in the docs example
http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html

**edit** I've edited this to show that the parameters passed to the Click function are in the different order. It was e, idx and should be idx, e.

Comment: You have the order wrong. It is 
```Click: function(idx, e) {
}
```